# Dell Studio 1555 upgrade to ssd, but cd-drive doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, dell-studio

I have a 3½ year old Dell Studio 1555, that I'm trying to upgrade. 
I've decided to install a 120 or 200gb SSD harddrive, this seems pretty straight forward - so this is not my headache. The diskdrive on the laptop broke about a year ago, when I insert discs it sounds like the arm is moving in a repeating pattern and nothing else happens - I can eject the disc though.

If I buy a SSD harddrive then how do I install Win7 from my reinstallation win7 dvd that I got when buying the laptop?

I'm thinking external diskdrives, maybe via usb - but I actually have no clue if it'll work. 
Has anyone got any ideas here? - I can't be the only one with no disc drive that has to reinstall a harddrive.

Thanks

Comment: A new optical disk drive will cost you $20 at most http://www.amazon.com/Asus-24xDVD-RW-Serial-Internal-DRW-24B1ST/dp/B0033Z2BAQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1374754034&sr=8-1&keywords=dvd+drive just replace it.  There are hundreds of tutorials of how to make a bootable USB Windows 7 installation drive just follow one of those.

Answer (score 3):

If you have good internet connection, then you can download your windows 7 version [here](https://superuser.com/a/305434/239735) (you still need a legit key ofcourse).
Then you can use [Microsoft own tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) to make a bootable windows 7 USB.

- Start up *Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool* when you have downloaded and installed it
- Select the iso file you downloaded in the *Source* field and click *Next*
- Insert your USB drive which you want to use (4GB is enough)
- Select *USB DEVICE* and click *Next*
- Select the USB device you want to use and click *BEGIN COPYING*

When it is done, you should have a working bootable Windows 7 USB