# An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader, bcd

My laptop is not getting started, it's unable to boot Windows 7. It shows the following error:

```
File:  \Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc000014c
info: an error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.
```

How can I boot my Windows?

Comment: also i dont have external recovery disk , just internal recovery on system hard disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows Boot Menu

First of all try to tap F8 when the computer is booting, untill you see the Windows boot menu and then select `Use last known good configuration`.
If Windows has worked before, then you might have a chance that this works.

### BCD Repair

I don't think that you are that lucky, because it's the BCD which looks like being damaged. and since it is a very essential part of Windows, then it will require some sort of bootable Windows installation disk to repair.

Check out my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/624071/dell-studio-1555-upgrade-to-ssd-but-cd-drive-doesnt-work/624076#624076) on how to make a bootable Windows 7 installation USB.

[Repair Windows BCD](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html) - This will guide you through how to repair and hopefully getting your Windows 7 back to starting normally again.

### Factory reset

A last thing you could try is a Factory reset.
This is will put your computer back to the state where you started the computer for the first time.
You can find a guide on how to do this on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: tried many things. at last factory reset is the best option

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution at least :)